# Command line makes the Nextjs application run in the background?

Tags: next.js

I have simple code Nextjs:

- When I run command: npm run dev // http://localhost:3000 Working well
- But when I run background: pm2 start npm --name "nextjs-13" -- start // http://localhost:3000 Not working

Which command makes the nextjs application run in the background on linux?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to build your Next.js application using `npm run build`. Once the build is finished you can then call the following command:

```bash
pm2 start --name="next-13" npm -- run start
```

Then you should be able to see the running process using `pm2 ls`. You can stop the process by calling `pm2 {app-name}`.

[image]

This is **not** the most ideal way to start your application. When going into production try using a [ecosystem file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#ecosystem-file) or write your own start script.